# textbox binding is not causing validation

Tags: c#, winforms, events, data-binding, textbox

I have 2 text boxes in a form, in both textbox `validating` events I have written code to validate the user input.. in `validated` event I update 3rd textbox based on these two textbox values

in form load I bind the text boxes to load previous data from database..as follows

```
this.txtClosingBalance.DataBindings
    .Add("Text", openingClosingBalance, "ClosingBalance");
```

Now problem is, when data is bound from database, validating events are not fired.. and 3rd textBox is not updated..

How to solve the problem? what is the work-around?

Answer (score 1):

If the `Validating` event is not fired, call it yourself when you do the binding:

```
this.txtClosingBalance.DataBindings.Add("Text", openingClosingBalance, 
    "ClosingBalance");
textBox_Validating(textBox, null);
```